# Google safe browsing returning 400 bad request

Tags: f#, google-api, f#-data, safe-browsing

Google is returning a 400 bad request; but what is wrong with the request?

```
open FSharp.Data

let apiKey = "key goes here - removed for stackoverflow"

let postUrl = "http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/downloads"
let testArray = "2\nhttp://www.google.com/\nhttp://ianfette.org/"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let foo2 = Http.Request(postUrl, httpMethod = "Post",
        query   = [ "client", "api"; "apikey", apiKey; "appver", "1.0"; "pver", "2.2" ],
        body = TextRequest (testArray)
        )

    0
```

I have verified that my key is correct by successfully executing get requests, it is only the post that is failing.

Comment: I think that a reason in the incorrect request body. If you change it like this ```let testArray = "goog-malware-shavar;\ngoogpub-phish-shavar;"``` (body from google example) then it will work.

Comment: Actually "The request’s body contains several lines separated by LF. The first line is a number indicating how many URLs are included in the body." https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/lookup_guide#AQuickExamplePOSTMethod

Comment: Yes, but for this call you should change `postUrl` and version numbers:  ```let postUrl = "https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup"``` and ```... "appver", "1.5.2"; "pver", "3.0"...```.

Comment: Sergey: Good catch, I did have the wrong URL. Unfortunately I still can't get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I updated FSharp.Data to version 2.0.5 (released 2014-03-29) this started working. I can only assume that there was a bug in the previous version that is now fixed.

[release notes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data/2.0.5) state:

> Added - to the list of default missing values. Re-added support for
>   specifying known HTTP headers in the wrong case. Fixed sending of HTTP
>   requests when using a portable class library version of FSharp.Data in
>   the full .NET version.

Here is the final (working) code:

```
open FSharp.Data

let apiKey = "key goes here"

let postUrl = "https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup"
let testArray = "2\nhttp://www.google.com/\nhttp://ianfette.org/"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let foo2 = Http.Request(postUrl, httpMethod = "Post",
        query   = [ "client", "api"; "apikey", apiKey; "appver", "1.5.2"; "pver", "3.0" ],
        body = TextRequest (testArray)
        )

    0
```

Thank you to Sergey Tihon for finding the error in my URL string in the question.

Comment: Humm, I have no idea how my fix solved your problem, but I'm glad it did :) Were you using the net40 version or any of the pcl's?

Comment: Gustavo: Using .Net framework 4.5.1 and F# 3.1 (FSHarp.Core 4.3.1.0) Added FSharp.Data using NuGet Package Manager in Visusl Studio 2013 Ultimate, always using latest stable version.